# How to update queues with gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I previously was using `appcfg.py` to deploy my (python) applications on Google AppEngine, but I recently switched to the `gcloud` command.

For updating the queues, I was doing :

```
/opt/google/google_appengine/appcfg.py -A project-id update_queues .
```

But now with ‘gcloud‘ I don't know how I can do that?

For information, here's how I deploy a new version now :

```
gcloud app deploy --project project-id app.yaml
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Does `gcloud app deploy queues.yaml` not do the trick?

Comment: Hum it does seems to work, but I believed it would deploy it on an other version than my current one. Isn't it the case with "queues.yaml"?

Comment: Ok it's all good, I understood while deploying app.yaml AND queue.yaml, Gcloud showed me the path, and app.yaml with in project-id/default/{version} while queue.yaml was in project-id/queue (version independant!). You can put your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10):

The cloud sdk deploy command supports multiple config files `index.yaml, queue.yaml, dispatch.yaml, dos.yaml, cron.yaml`

> ```
> gcloud app deploy [DEPLOYABLES …]
> ```
>
> [DEPLOYABLES …]
>
> The yaml files for the services or configurations you want to deploy. If not given, defaults to app.yaml in the current directory. If that is not found, attempts to automatically generate necessary configuration files (such as app.yaml) in the current directory.

*https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy*

So:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml queue.yaml
```